# Reload Partial View in AngularJS Routing

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a Partial view like this :

```
        @model StudentPro.Models.TblUser
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- END SAMPLE FORM PORTLET-->
            <!-- BEGIN SAMPLE FORM PORTLET-->
            <div class="portlet light">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <i class="fa fa-users font-green-sharp"></i>
                        <span class="caption-subject font-green-sharp bold uppercase">ویرایش کاربر</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tools">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portlet-body form">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                        <div class="form-horizontal">

                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IDUsers)

                            <div class="form-group">
...
```

I load this partial using angularjs routing and using ng-view, but sometimes when I change some data in another page and I come back to this partial, the page is cached and I see the older data. When I refresh the page with F5, it shows the new data.

Is there some way to reload the partial view to reflect the new data using anguarjs? Something like this:

```
$route.reload("#/users")
```